# Estou com um problema para fazer upload de uma imagem em Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload

não estou conseguindo acharo erro, quando tento enviar uma imagem

arquivo.html

```
  <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Título</label>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" placeholder="Título artigo" /><br><br>

        <label>Conteúdo</label>
        <textarea name="conteudo" id="trumbowyg-editor" rows="5" placeholder="Conteúdo do artigo"></textarea><br><br>
</form>
```

arquivo.js

```
! function(r) {
    "use strict";
    var a = {
        serverPath: "http://localhost/textarea/imagens",
        fileFieldName: "fileToUpload",
        data: [],
        headers: {},
        xhrFields: {},
        urlPropertyName: "file",
        statusPropertyName: "success",
        success: void 0,
        error: void 0,
        imageWidthModalEdit: !1
    };

    function o(r, a) {
        var e = a.shift(),
            l = a;
        if (null !== r) {
            if (0 === l.length) return r[e];
            if ("object" == typeof r) return o(r[e], l)
        }
        return r
    }! function() {
        if (!r.trumbowyg.addedXhrProgressEvent) {
            var a = r.ajaxSettings.xhr;
            r.ajaxSetup({
                xhr: function() {
                    var r = this,
                        o = a();
                    return o && "object" == typeof o.upload && void 0 !== r.progressUpload && o.upload.addEventListener("progress", (function(a) {
                        r.progressUpload(a)
                    }), !1), o
                }
            }), r.trumbowyg.addedXhrProgressEvent = !0
        }
    }(), r.extend(!0, r.trumbowyg, {
        langs: {
            en: {
                upload: "Upload",
                file: "File",
                uploadError: "Error"
            },
            pt_br: {
                upload: "Enviar do local",
                file: "Arquivo",
                uploadError: "Erro"
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            upload: {
                init: function(e) {
                    e.o.plugins.upload = r.extend(!0, {}, a, e.o.plugins.upload || {});
                    var l = {
                        fn: function() {
                            e.saveRange();
                            var a, l = e.o.prefix,
                                d = {
                                    file: {
                                        type: "file",
                                        required: !0,
                                        attributes: {
                                            accept: "image/*"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    alt: {
                                        label: "description",
                                        value: e.getRangeText()
                                    }
                                };
                            e.o.plugins.upload.imageWidthModalEdit && (d.width = {
                                value: ""
                            });
                            var t = !1,
                                i = e.openModalInsert(e.lang.upload, d, (function(d) {
                                    if (!t) {
                                        t = !0;
                                        var u = new FormData;
                                        u.append(e.o.plugins.upload.fileFieldName, a), e.o.plugins.upload.data.map((function(r) {
                                            u.append(r.name, r.value)
                                        })), r.map(d, (function(r, a) {
                                            "file" !== a && u.append(a, r)
                                        })), 0 === r("." + l + "progress", i).length && r("." + l + "modal-title", i).after(r("<div/>", {
                                            class: l + "progress"
                                        }).append(r("<div/>", {
                                            class: l + "progress-bar"
                                        }))), r.ajax({
                                            url: e.o.plugins.upload.serverPath,
                                            headers: e.o.plugins.upload.headers,
                                            xhrFields: e.o.plugins.upload.xhrFields,
                                            type: "POST",
                                            data: u,
                                            cache: !1,
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            processData: !1,
                                            contentType: !1,
                                            progressUpload: function(a) {
                                                r("." + l + "progress-bar").css("width", Math.round(100 * a.loaded / a.total) + "%")
                                            },
                                            success: function(a) {
                                                if (e.o.plugins.upload.success) e.o.plugins.upload.success(a, e, i, d);
                                                else if (o(a, e.o.plugins.upload.statusPropertyName.split("."))) {
                                                    var l = o(a, e.o.plugins.upload.urlPropertyName.split("."));
                                                    e.execCmd("insertImage", l, !1, !0);
                                                    var u = r('img[src="' + l + '"]:not([alt])', e.$box);
                                                    u.attr("alt", d.alt), e.o.plugins.upload.imageWidthModalEdit && parseInt(d.width) > 0 && u.attr({
                                                        width: d.width
                                                    }), setTimeout((function() {
                                                        e.closeModal()
                                                    }), 250), e.$c.trigger("tbwuploadsuccess", [e, a, l])
                                                } else e.addErrorOnModalField(r("input[type=file]", i), e.lang[a.message]), e.$c.trigger("tbwuploaderror", [e, a]);
                                                t = !1
                                            },
                                            error: e.o.plugins.upload.error || function() {
                                                e.addErrorOnModalField(r("input[type=file]", i), e.lang.uploadError), e.$c.trigger("tbwuploaderror", [e]), t = !1
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                }));
                            r("input[type=file]").on("change", (function(r) {
                                try {
                                    a = r.target.files[0]
                                } catch (o) {
                                    a = r.target.value
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    };
                    e.addBtnDef("upload", l)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Olá, esse componente não reflete a sua pergunta. Até porque ele esta minify , não é o fonte original o que torna ilegível. Faça um exemplo mínimo, diga o que você esta usando (Jquery,  plugins e versões ) , não coloque todo o componente de download porque o objetivo do stackoverflow não é te ajudar a corrigir o código, é te ajudar a tirar dúvidas. Então, crie todas as dúvidas que você tem e que não conseguiu achar na internet usando o google e pergunte uma a uma colocando o menor código possível que exemplifique o seu problema.  Só assim conseguiremos te dar algum apoio, espero ter ajudado.